# ¿Cómo puedo centrar este menú de navegación?

Tags: html, css

Aquí esta el código, pongo el fragmento del menú porque lo demás es código básico de una estructura de html5, abajo están los estilos

```css
h1 {
  font-family: verdana;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(images.jpg);
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.enlaces {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #34c6eb;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>

  <a href="#" class="enlaces">Inicio</a>
  <a href="#" class="enlaces">Nosotros</a>
  <a href="#" class="enlaces">Tutoriales</a>
  <a href="#" class="enlaces">Contactos</a>

</nav>
```

Comment: revise grid layout, le puede servir. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Answer (score 4):

Usa la propiedad `text-align` con el valor`center` para que tu nav se centre en base a body

```css
 h1{
      font-family: verdana;
       text-align: center;
       background: url(images.jpg);
        height: 50px;
      color: white;
       }


        .enlaces{


         display: inline-block;
        background: #34c6eb;
       color: #fff;
         padding: 10px 30px;
          text-decoration: none;
             }
             
             nav{
             text-align:center;
             }
```

```html
<nav>

    <a href="#" class = "enlaces">Inicio</a>
       <a href="#" class=  "enlaces">Nosotros</a>
     <a href="#" class =  "enlaces">Tutoriales</a>
       <a href="#" class = "enlaces">Contactos</a>

      </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

No estás aprovechando el tag de `nav`, en tu caso te recomiendo que trates lo siguiente:

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <a href="#" class="enlaces">Inicio</a>
  <a href="#" class="enlaces">Nosotros</a>
  <a href="#" class="enlaces">Tutoriales</a>
  <a href="#" class="enlaces">Contactos</a>
</nav>

.navbar { 
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
```

En tu clase de "enlaces", puedes eliminar `display: inline-block;`, creo sería como repetir código, ya no lo necesitas porque estás usando flex.

Answer (score 0):

*Con esto espero que puedas solucionar tu problema de tu navegacion*

> Hola Amigo creo que esto seria una solución que si te pueda servir

**Espero aver ayudado**

> Con padding-left creo que seria una forma de solucionar tu problema ya que esto te permite dar espacio a los lados..............
>
> Pruebalo aver si te funciona
>   **thx**

*Solo hago relleno ejejejeje*

1. El padding-left te proporciona dar distancia  de la pagina de la izquierda
   estoy rellenando este texto no se de tantas palabras  lo siento

*Bueno amigo cualquier cosa me comentas en los comentarios me avisas si te funciono para ver como lo solucionamos si quieres dar mas espacio al lado izquierdo o derecho solo aumentas los px no hay problema*

```css
h1 {
  font-family: verdana;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(images.jpg);
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.enlaces {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #34c6eb;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navigation {
 padding-left:75px;
 padding-right:0px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<div id="navigation">
  <a href="#" class="enlaces">Inicio</a>
  <a href="#" class="enlaces">Nosotros</a>
  <a href="#" class="enlaces">Tutoriales</a>
  <a href="#" class="enlaces">Contactos</a>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es otra solución, aunque yo preferiría el uso de flexbox ;)

```css
h1 {
  font-family: verdana;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(images.jpg);
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.enlaces {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #34c6eb;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav{
  max-width:500px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<nav>

  <a href="#" class="enlaces">Inicio</a>
  <a href="#" class="enlaces">Nosotros</a>
  <a href="#" class="enlaces">Tutoriales</a>
  <a href="#" class="enlaces">Contactos</a>

</nav>
```

Comment: Por favor considera leer [answer], editar y agregar una explicación a tu código pues los aportes que son solo scripts se consideran de baja calidad